# How do you get Messages to go online automatically during login?

Tags: macos, messages

How do I get Messages to go online when I start my Mac? It does start automatically but doesn't go online automatically. Any idea how?

PS:
I should mention that I am not talking about iMessage but the Messages chat application that lets you interface with gtalk, yahoo messenger etc.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this.

First, if you have messages set up in notifications, then you'll get your messages even if Messages is closed (and you can send messages from the notifications as well).

Second, if you actually want to launch Messages at login, add Messages to your Login Items list in the User & Groups system preference.

[image: Add a login item that will start when you login]

Comment: I already have Messages setup to start at login (as mentioned in the question) but it doesnt login automatically. Also I should mention that I am not talking about iMessage but the Messages chat application that lets you interface with gtalk, yahoo messenger etc.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the *"When I quit messages set my status to offline"* box in Messages preferences.

Your status will be set to Available next time you log in and/or unlock your computer.

[image: Messages Prefs]